# How can I only package production dependencies when using serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using `serverless` to package lambda implemented by `typescript`. I have defined `serverless.yml` and I found `serverless deploy` will zip all `node_modules` directory and upload to s3 bucket as lambda file. My pakcage.json has `dependencies` and `devDependencies` and I'd like to exclude dev deps. I know that I can do something like below:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - '!node_modules/node-fetch/**'
```

but I have to exclude them one by one which is not a good idea.

Another way I can think of is to run build and deploy command in a docker container where only download production dependencies. However, it is a little slow since each time I have to spinner up a container and run `yarn install --only=production` command to download these dependencies.

so I am looking for a better solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can exclude dev deps like this.

```
package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
```

Spinning up docker and inistalling deps from within it is actually a better idea. Even though it takes some more time to spin it up before deployment. Some deps might have compiled binaries and if you yarn install them locally and then deploy, they might not work on a remote server.

Aside from this, have you tried parcel bundler and with `serverless-simple-parcel` plugin?
Here is a sample configuration for it (goes into serverless.yml into the custom block):

```
custom:
  parcel:
    entries:
      - file: src/handler.ts
        target: node
        outFile: handler.js
    options:
      publicUrl: .
```

Comment: Does `serverless deploy` run `npm install` on my project?

Comment: That should not be needed, as this flag is activated by default. You actually have to opt out if you want your dev dependencies to be included: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/#development-dependencies